# Can not recompile pdflatex.fmt to resolve "pdflatex.fmt made by a different executable"

Tags: pdftex, format-files, fmtutil

Originally, I was getting this "made by different executable" error with pandoc, and later with everything that has anything to do with generating PDFs through the pdflatex engine.

As per the error message, my executables have been changed (because my system underwent an update) but the corresponding .fmt file(s) has not. I'm using Arch Linux and the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/TeX_Live/FAQ) has said pacman -S to take care of rebuilding the format files when updating, but in my case, that has seemed not to happen.

Using `fmtutil`:

```
sudo fmtutil-sys --all | grep -P "(INFO|ERROR)"
```

still leaves out `pdflatex.fmt` from being built. Here's the output

```
fmtutil [INFO]: writing formats under /var/lib/texmf/web2c
fmtutil [INFO]: --- remaking luajithbtex with luajithbtex
fmtutil [INFO]: log file copied to: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/luajithbtex/luajithbtex.log
fmtutil [INFO]: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/luajithbtex/luajithbtex.fmt installed.
fmtutil [INFO]: --- remaking luatex with luatex
fmtutil [INFO]: log file copied to: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/luatex/luatex.log
fmtutil [INFO]: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/luatex/luatex.fmt installed.
fmtutil [INFO]: --- remaking pdftex with pdftex
fmtutil [INFO]: log file copied to: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/pdftex.log
fmtutil [INFO]: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/pdftex.fmt installed.
fmtutil [INFO]: --- remaking luajittex with luajittex
fmtutil [INFO]: log file copied to: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/luajittex/luajittex.log
fmtutil [INFO]: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/luajittex/luajittex.fmt installed.
fmtutil [INFO]: --- remaking luahbtex with luahbtex
fmtutil [INFO]: log file copied to: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/luahbtex/luahbtex.log
fmtutil [INFO]: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/luahbtex/luahbtex.fmt installed.
fmtutil [INFO]: --- remaking tex with tex
fmtutil [INFO]: log file copied to: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/tex/tex.log
fmtutil [INFO]: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/tex/tex.fmt installed.
fmtutil [INFO]: --- remaking dviluatex with luatex
fmtutil [INFO]: log file copied to: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/luatex/dviluatex.log
fmtutil [INFO]: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/luatex/dviluatex.fmt installed.
fmtutil [INFO]: --- remaking mf with mf-nowin
fmtutil [INFO]: log file copied to: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/metafont/mf.log
fmtutil [INFO]: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/metafont/mf.base installed.
fmtutil [INFO]: --- remaking etex with pdftex
fmtutil [INFO]: log file copied to: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/etex.log
fmtutil [INFO]: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/etex.fmt installed.
fmtutil [INFO]: --- remaking pdfetex with pdftex
fmtutil [INFO]: log file copied to: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/pdfetex.log
fmtutil [INFO]: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/pdfetex.fmt installed.
fmtutil [INFO]: disabled formats: 1
fmtutil [INFO]: successfully rebuilt formats: 10
fmtutil [INFO]: total formats: 11
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 0
```

I'm suspecting that the `disabled formats: 1` is actually the pdflatex.fmt and fmtutil is simply ignoring the fact that pdflatex.fmt has to be rebuilt (but I don't know how to verify this). Upon further [research](https://comp.text.tex.narkive.com/iLbGoobY/creating-missing-pdflatex-fmt):
I found some hints which suggest fmtutil should contain something that will tell fmtutil to generate the format file I want.

> 1. Get the files pdflatex.ini and pdftexconfig.tex (e. g. from the TeX
>    Live or another distribution)
> 2. Place the file pdflatex.ini in
>    path_to_your_texmf_tree/texmf/pdftex/latex/config/
> 3. Place the file pdftexconfig.tex in
>    path_to_your_texmf_tree/texmf/tex/generic/config/
> 4. Run texhash as superuser/root
> 5. Run fmtutil --missing as superuser/root
>    I hope this helps other people just like your help in this newsgroup

I'm not sure of the first step, where can I obtain a different fmtutil.cnf? Is there any other way to recompile pdflatex.fmt?